# Convert STRING DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM to YY-MM-DD HH:SS

Tags: sql, date, datetime, parsing, google-bigquery

I want to convert a number of rows in this STRING format:

```
21/03/2019 10:30
```

to:

```
2019-03-21 10:30
```

I've achieved this before when the string was slightly different but it just isn't working for some reason. This is one of the examples I've used (startdate is my column name)

SELECT
(PARSE_DATETIME("%D/%m/%Y %T",startdate)) as start_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out:

(PARSE_DATETIME("%d/%m/%Y %R",startdate) as start_date